# update row in oracle using data from same table

Tags: oracle, sql-update

Hi I have the following table and I want to update the rows with same group where if the pervious row that have count zero have value I want to populate the other one with it if the row that needs to be populated was null otherwise no changes will be done.

Table 1 before update:

Group | Count | Name   | lastName |

Grp1  |   0   |  tyler |   calark  |

Grp1  |    1   |  lara  |   jason   |

Grp1  |     2   | null  |   spark   |

Table 1 after update:

Group | Count | Name   | lastName |

Grp1  |   0   |  tyler |   calark  |

Grp1  |    1   |  lara  |   jason   |

Grp1  |     2   | tyler |   spark   |

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood it.

Before:

```
SQL> select * From test;

CGROUP         CCOUNT NAME       LAST_NAME
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
D1                  0 tyler      clark
D1                  1 jason      lara
D1                  2            spark
```

Update:

```
SQL> update test a set
  2    a.name = (select b.name
  3              from test b
  4              where b.cgroup = a.cgroup
  5                and b.ccount = 0
  6             )
  7  where a.name is null;

1 row updated.
```

After:

```
SQL> select * From test;

CGROUP         CCOUNT NAME       LAST_NAME
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
D1                  0 tyler      clark
D1                  1 jason      lara
D1                  2 tyler      spark

SQL>
```

Comment: yes thank you and if I want to do more than one column at same time I need two queries or one is enough

Comment: One query should be enough, you'd modify line #2 to e.g. `(a.name, a.last_name) = (select b.name, b.last_name`

Comment: if name is null and last name is not what will happen where i need it to be dynamic where if name is null take only name,same thing for last name,and if both are null take both

Comment: Use NVL: `... = (select nvl(a.name, b.name), nvl(a.last_name, b.last_name)`